# How to check if any of the n given tiles overlap

Tags: c++

Here is the problem:
I have a floor. I am given an array of n tiles which are defined by the coordinates of the lower left corner and the upper right corner (x1, y1, x2, y2). I have to check if **any two** tiles are overlapping. What is the fastest algorithm to do this? I assume you would sort the array by x or y (or some other way), but I don't know how to continue from there.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Just to clarify, I know how to check if 2 tiles are overlapping, what I need is to check all the tiles fast. The simplest solution is to check every combination of tiles, but that is wasting time and resources, I want to know what is the fastest way to do it.

Comment: You may search for "collision detection AABB" (axis aligned bounding boxes) because your problem sounds like if AABB CD solves it.

Comment: I'll look it up, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two blocks like this:

```
blockA = {x1, y1, x2, y2}
blockB = {x3, y3, x4, y4}
```

And then, Do,

```
(blockA.x1 - blockB.x4) * (blockA.x2 - blockB.x3) = X
(blockA.y1 - blockB.y4) * (blockA.y2 - blockB.y3) = Y
```

if X < 0 and Y < 0, it's overlapped.

Comment: blockA and blockB can be changed, like B - A.
A - B or B - A is all your choice.